# Unable to install GNOME Boxes

Tags: software-installation, 12.10, compiling, gnome-boxes

I can't install GNOME Boxes:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-boxes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-boxes is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-boxes' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to compile GNOME Boxes:

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
[...]
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.22... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.40.0... 0.50.2 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.14.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for gobject-introspection... configure: error: gobject-introspection-1.0 is not installed
```

But `gobject-introspection` is already installed :

```
$ sudo apt-get install gobject-introspection 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gobject-introspection is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Why am I unable to install GNOME Boxes?

Answer (score 2):

I have GNOME Boxes installed and running on Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal (actually Ubuntu Gnome Remix with the GNOME3 PPA activated).

According to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-boxes), you can find the package `gnome-boxes` in the *universe* repository which is activated by default. Check if it's still the case, resynchronize the package index files, upgrade and try installing GNOME Boxes again :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-boxes
```

If it doesn't work, maybe you can add the GNOME3 PPA and try installing it again since it seems to be the only difference between our configurations :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

This PPA offers packages that were not included by default in Ubuntu. Be careful not to upgrade and to remove it after, if you don't want it.

Rémi.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are running the 32 bit version of Ubuntu. According to the [Launchpad entry](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/gnome-boxes) for GNOME Boxes, it is only available for the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 12.10 (A post on [webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html) says this is due to a bug).

Fortunately, this looks like it will be fixed in Ubuntu 13.04, because [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/gnome-boxes) says the package will be available for both the i386 and amd64 architectures.

Answer (score 0):

To quote another this fixed my issue when running `./configure`

> Have you installed the package `libgirepository1.0-dev`? I think it's the package which contains the  `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc` file needed when the configure script is executed. I'm not sure how it's named for Linux Mint12 (that name is for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it via [FLATHUB](https://askubuntu.com/a/1429513/983917), follow the link the issue was already discussed