# How to update to the absolute latest version of gnome-boxes?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-boxes

What is the command line for upgrading to latest update to gnome-boxes?

The 20.04 official repo points to an older version of boxes, but I don't know how to force latest change. Thanks!

Comment: If you're looking for bleeding edge, then you'll need to [clone the git repository](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-boxes) and compile the source code.

Comment: There's also the version up at [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Boxes).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the project's GitHub [repo](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-boxes): download on [FLATHUB](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Boxes), you can do it via running the commands:

Step 1: [Install Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu) :

```
sudo apt install -y flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
# To complete setup, restart your system
```

Step 2: Install Gnome Boses

```
flatpak install boxes
```

Comment: Virtual machine periodically freezing, whatever task is running even it can be one opened window. `version 42.3`